# working with salesforce currency fields

Tags: currency

I have to perform some calculations on two currency field in the following manner and display in the UI:

field1*field2/field2

So i have the following code for this:

```
Decimal value1 = object.field1;
Decimal value2 = object.field2;
Decimal result = value1*value2/value2;
```

But this is throwing error:Invalid type.

Comment: You do realize `value1*value2/value2 == value1` right?

Comment: Unless `value2` is `0` or `null`, in which case the calculation will throw errors.

Comment: oops, my bad. The formula is (value1-value2)/value2.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please verify that your fields are indeed Currency fields? This operation (although as correctly stated by Adrian), this operation does not make sense, should work with Decimals.

With `System.debug(object.field1 instanceof Decimal);` you can test if object.field1 indeed is a Decimal.